# How to capture watir webdriver requests in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webdriver, watir-webdriver

I am using [watir-webdriver](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver) gem and [webdriver-user-agent](https://github.com/alisterscott/webdriver-user-agent) to perform a automation test in rails. I want to capture a mobile user agent requests and its parameters.

Can we capture the requests using [Charles proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).If possible how can i use it. Can anyone tell me steps for it.

Comment: Yes. We can use Charles proxy. we need to install the add on in firefox browser to capture the requests.

Comment: If you answered your own question then you should post that as your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. We can use Charles proxy. we need to install the charles proxy add on in firefox browser to capture the requests